# Why can't this polynomial vanish except when $x+y=0,xy= 0$?

Tags: polynomials

Show that for any $x, y \in \mathbb R$ with $x + y \neq 0,xy\neq 0$

$$p(x,y) := x^6-2 x^5 y+2 x^5-x^4 y^2-2 x^4 y+x^4+4 x^3 y^3+2 x^3 y-x^2 y^4-4 x^2 y^3-4 x^2 y^2+2 x^2 y-2 x y^5+6 x y^4+2 x y^3+y^6-2 y^5-y^4-2 y^3+y^2 \neq 0$$

I'm sorry,I forget $xy\neq 0$,Now I think it's hold?

Comment: It isn't even 0 when $x+y=0$

Comment: This question would be much improved if you included some context and/or motivation. Give people a reason to care about this problem.

Comment: It is from a elementary queston: if $$\left(\sqrt{y^{2} - x\,\,}\, - x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^{2} + y\,\,}\, - y\right)=y$$
then  $x+y=0$.

Comment: Then that should be included *in the question*. Not in a comment.

Comment: Meanwhile, however, I tried seeing what solutions there are when $y = 1$. I seem to get $p(x, 1) = x^6 - 2x^4 + 6x^3 - 7x^2 + 6x - 3$. (Even if I made an arithmetic mistake, the leading term is $x^6$ and the constant term is $-3$.) At $x = 0$ we have $p(0, 1) = -3$, and $p(x, 1) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is $r > 0$ such that $p(r, 1) = 0$. And then $(x, y) = (r, 1)$ satisfies $xy \neq 0$ and $x + y \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

I find p(-1,0)=0. Typo?

This sentence filled in to satisfy 30 character minimum.